# Callback after .swap() not working - ASP.NET SPA w/sammy.js

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sammy.js

I am building a Single Page Application using ASP.NET and sammy.js, where all views except for the Home/Index view are rendered as partial views so that sammy can swap out the content of the main body with the partial view that is returned.

I am using the example given [here](http://blog.apterainc.com/bid/313071/Turn-your-ASP-NET-MVC-app-into-a-Single-Page-Application-with-one-classy-Sammy-js-route), and everything loads fine as expected.

Similar to the above example, in my Home/Index page I have reference to a script called routing.js, which wraps the sammy function call in order to parse the MVC route:

```
var Routing = function (appRoot, contentSelector, defaultRoute) {

    function getUrlFromHash(hash) {
        var url = hash.replace('#/', '');
        if (url === appRoot)
            url = defaultRoute;
        return url;
    }

    return {
        init: function () {
            Sammy(contentSelector, function () {
                this.get(/\#\/(.*)/, function (context) {
                    var url = getUrlFromHash(context.path);
                    context.load(url).swap();
                });
            }).run('#/');
        }
    };
}
```

I need to call a callback function after the content swap has fully completed in order to implement further jQuery functionality on the newly rendered content.  My dilemma is that no matter what option I try from the sammy.js docs, nothing seems to run the callback after the content has been swapped.

I have tried all of the following (all "valid" ways of passing a callback according to the sammy.js docs):

```
content.load(url).swap(pageLoadScripts(url));
content.load(url).swap().onComplete(pageLoadScripts(url));
content.load(url).swap().then(pageLoadScripts(url));
content.load(url).swap().next(pageLoadScripts(url));
content.load(url,pageLoadScripts(url)).swap();
```

and even

```
content.load(url).swap();
pageLoadScripts(url);
```

In every case the pageLoadScripts function fires off prior to the content being swapped.  Any ideas or suggestions on what to do differently?

Comment: Did you ever find a decent solution for this problem? Have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a hack, but it works.

Inside the Sammy initialization function, I added the following override to the swap function just before the override to the get function:

```
this.swap = function (content, callback) {
    var context = this;
    context.$element().html(content);
    pageLoadScripts(hashedUrl);
};
```

FWIW, I still have not been able to get callback to be anything other than 'undefined', even in this override function.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get this working:

```
// override for callback after page load
this.swap = function(content, callback) {
    this.$element().html(content);
    if (callback) {
        callback();
    }
};

// users
this.get('/#/users', function(context) {
    context.load('/users').swap(function() { replaceBindings(viewModel.users); });
});
```

I managed to get the callback param to NOT be 'undefined' by wrapping it in another function.